# I tried to use the .map function but it didn't work on my code

Tags: javascript, axios, lodash

```js
async function getCategoryIds ()
{
    let response = axios.get( `${BASE_API_URL}categories?count=100` );
    let catIds = response.data.map( c => c.id );
    return _.samplesize( catIds, NUM_CATEGORIES )  
};
```

This is my code I tried to change the data in [] but it still don't work

Comment: How is this not working? Please [edit] your question to provide samples of the response data, the result you expect and the result you're actually getting

Comment: This should be throwing an error like _"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"_. Did you miss that somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is you have not used await in your code.
adding await like the following should solve your problem -

```
let response = await axios.get( `${BASE_API_URL}categories?count=100` );
```

Comment: Pretty much this. The explanation is that axios.get() is an async function and therefore returns a `Promise` which you need to handle correctly.